# Blue card holder employed by company in Germany may move to Sweden

Tags: germany, blue-card, sweden

I'm a non-European citizen who moved to Germany under the Blue card resident permit. It is now 21 months that I'm living and working in Germany. My manager proposed a project in the employer's customer in Sweden for a duration of 2 years.

My inquiries are:

1. Do I need to apply for a Swedish resident and work permit?
2. Will this 2 years expatriate affect my German Blue card permit?

Answer (score 1):

Under the EU blue card scheme you are allowed to leave the country for a temporary absence of less than 12 months without affecting the blue card validity of the blue card, and hence can return and continue at any stage.

During this period however you would be expected to continue to keep your primary residency in Germany which means:

- Continue to pay German tax on your worldwide income
- Continue to maintain your property in Germany
- Continue to pay health insurance in Germany

This period ***may*** be extendable upon specific agreement in advance with the Ausländerbehörde Amt(ABH)/Immigration office.  But you would have to have a good reason and need to negotiate this in person, in advance.

However, if you leave the country for a reason which is not considered temporary then the residence permit would become invalid.  Such reasons include:

- **To work**
- Attend school
- To marry and settle abroad

Example statement from Munich:
https://www.muenchen.de/rathaus/home_en/Department-of-Public-Order/Foreigners-Office/Expiry-of-residence-permit.html

Therefore, while a period of a few months working on a project in Sweden might be acceptable if seconded by your employer, a period of 2 years is too long.

You could apply for a Blue Card for Sweden, although the exact conditions may vary compared to Germany.  Although this is a new application and your cannot "transfer" your blue card from Germany, the fact that you had a Blue card in Germany would normally be seen as favourable.

Comment: Allthough not incorrect, the term **worldwide income** should not be understood as the term is used for US taxes.